# Is there a preferred way to format links?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, formatting

I was wondering if there is a preferred way to include links in posts.

Sometimes you see something like 'See this link [here](http://stackoverflow.com)' and other times you'll see something like 'See this link http://stackoverflow.com'.

Personally, I prefer the second case. You can see immediately where the link will take you. I realise, of course, that some links can be very long and would not add much to the readability of the post. Perhaps in such cases a link should be shown like this: 'See this link at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)'

Comment: Personally, I prefer the 3rd case, and I sometimes put the link for a portion of the text to cite the source. I find the "here" in the first case doesn't say anything about the link, and the bare link in the second case is rather "dirty".

Comment: Drop "this link"! I already know it's a link. I also know it's made of letters and other characters. No need to explain that either. Instead, make it descriptive of the target content, e.g. "See [this worked example on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)."

Answer (score 11):

"[Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0)" as link text has been frowned upon for as long as the web has existed.

The optimal hyperlink label, of course, is one that actually describes its destination, or at least consists of its name/title. Again, this is industry best practices and is not limited to Stack Overflow.

The one thing I have to note, for editors, is that when you see a link in a post that's just a bare URL, especially if that URL has a descriptive slug (for example, `is-there-a-preferred-way-to-format-links`), if you want to give that bare URL a label please give it a descriptive one. Don't just change it to "here". A descriptive bare URL is better than a nondescriptive link label.

Comment: It also might be worth mentioning that intra-SE URLs will be nicely formatted by the renderer. I.e., the text `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315992/is-there-a-preferred-way-to-format-links`, included directly in your post, will appear as `Is there a preferred way to format links?` in the browser.

Comment: Remember also that in a browser's  menu of links, a selection labelled `"here"`, `"here"` and `"here"` seems particularly unhelpful.  (Yes, I know that not all browsers provide this feature, but it's very handy where it's available).