# Hiding attribution of quoted material

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, attribution

I recently came across a suggested edit which I found questionable. Most of the edit was good, so it was finally approved.

However, one part of the post, similar to this:

> > Quoted material from external site
> > ...
>
> http://website.example/link/to/blog

was changed to:

> > Quoted material from external site
> > ...
>
> [Source](http://website.example/link/to/blog)

Thus effectively hiding the link behind the word "Source".

Since the content is quoted from an external site, I think that the link should have been kept as it was, or at the very least, that the name of the website should be clearly visible, as in:

> Source: [Website.example](http://website.example/link/to/blog)

---

I'm looking for opinions or references to official guidelines on this matter. My view is that this part of the edit was completely inappropriate.

---

<sub>Note: I specifically did not tag this with [suggested-edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suggested-edits) because my question is more about the appropriateness of attribution, than guidance for reviewing suggested edits.</sub>

Comment: I don't think that changing the verbose link to "Source" is hiding disclosure in any way. Usually I don't straight up post the link when quoting something, but do something like "See [Source]" or "In [this documentation]". As far as my experience goes, that is commonplace and widely accepted.

Comment: @Magisch "Source" can look a little neater than a raw URL, but you do need to provide something that will help future readers find the linked info in case the original link rots. That info doesn't _have_ to be given in the link text itself, but it does need to be obvious. FWIW, I tend to do stuff like "Please see [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) in the official Python docs".

Comment: (cont) Of course, this isn't required for links to Stack Exchange posts; in those cases I just use something like "Please see "[this MSO comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327344/hiding-attribution-of-quoted-material?cb=1#comment364482_327344)".

Comment: @PM2Ring I do stuff like "According to [the MYSQL manual]" or "According to [the C standard]"

Comment: I prefer the hidden version. It's almost guaranteed to be shorter and neater, and I don't trust URL text *ever*. Anyone using StackOverflow should be intelligent enough to know to mouse hover URLs and check the status bar before clicking on any link, regardless of what the poster named the link. I agree with Magisch's recommendations for naming links based on context where possible.

Comment: just because it says one thing that looks like a URL does not mean that is actually the URL it links to. At least with it says `Source` it gives  you pause to hover and see what it really links to.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[This help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) says:

> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from another site or in an answer on Stack Overflow) make sure you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

and provides an example that names the title of the source, rather than its author. Based on this, the guidelines clearly recommend naming the source and/or its author wherever possible.

If you're going to give a bare URL a human-readable label, make sure you give it a meaningful label. Otherwise, *leave the bare URL alone*. A clickable bare URL that contains meaningful information is better than (what is basically) "Click here."

If the bare URL itself contains misleading information, point this out in a comment for the benefit of other readers. The content is still plagiarized if the link indeed does not point to the original source.

Some users have been known to use vague labels such as "Source" and "Reference" to hide either misleading source links (links that don't actually contain the text being quoted), or worse, *spam* (though the latter is much rarer IME). Watch out for these.

See also:

- The "Attribution" section of my answer to [Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed/321326#321326)
- [Is there a preferred way to format links?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315992/is-there-a-preferred-way-to-format-links/315993#315993)

Answer (score 11):

From disclosure perspective those are the same and I would definitely reject suggested edit that

- changes `http://website.example/link/to/blog`
- to `[source](http://website.example/link/to/blog)`

as it does not make the post even little more readable.

Comment: It is not entirely true that *all* external links on Stack Overflow are nofollow. There is an undocumented algorithm that takes into account the age of the post and its score so that "reputable" links get the Google juice. See [this question on MSE for details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111279/remove-nofollow-on-links-deemed-reputable). That may have been tweaked even more since 2011. But the spirit is still accurate, most links in questions and answers will be nofollow.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks - wasn't aware of that detail

Comment: Besides I think it is less a matter of SEO than having [accessible link text](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H30.html)

Comment: @Rhumborl: That's silly. We all know websites were designed for search engines, not humans!