# Has the community bot changed too much in changing HTTP links to HTTPS?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ssl

I have asked [a question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346020/what-is-the-official-moderator-statement-about-low-quality-flags-in-the-help-and). I could swear at the time the following URLs are replaced by the actual title. (Which my simple test of copying a URL into this question confirms).

After the change from the Community Bot, we only have the URLs instead of the titles:

[image]

Of course I could change the titles by myself, but I am sure this question is not the only case, where this occurs.

Is it possible to rerun the bot, to consider titles instead of URLs?

---

After reviewing all questions, I see that the first one has a replaced title. This question is still available on Stack Overflow. The not replaced URLs are all deleted. But these posts are still in the database, aren't they?

Comment: It's because the url->title trick uses the public api which doesn't have access to deleted questions. So, it's expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned, this only works with questions that aren't deleted because deleted questions simply don't exist as far as the public API is concerned. There's a reason they're called *deleted* questions after all. There's not much that can be done about this from a technical point of view unless the titles of deleted questions were made available to the public API, but considering that question URLs *normally* come with title slugs anyway, this doesn't seem to be a compelling problem.

However, this does bring up a good point regarding URLs versus links with description text. I've [stated in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315992/is-there-a-preferred-way-to-format-links/315993#315993) that bare URLs containing full title slugs (or even just keyword slugs) are better off that way than edited into things like "click here" or "reference" or "more info" or "enter link description here", all of which make the links objectively *worse* by removing all relevant information from the URLs.

And this is what really annoys me about using share URLs to link to questions and answers within the site:

- Share URLs, for the sake of brevity, don't include question slugs.
- Share URLs, for obvious reasons, only progress the Announcer, Booster and Publicist badges when visited from outside the network. Within the network, they do absolutely nothing other than waste a redirect. Granted, answers don't have slugs anyway, but for questions there really is no excuse when you can simply copy the link from the question title.

When the questions they link to get deleted, you end up with something like this (taking from one of the examples in your question):

https://stackoverflow.com/q/42992434/106224

... which *is* what I would consider a bare URL that does need to be edited.

But even if share URLs are affected more than full URLs with slugs, the majority of deleted questions aren't worth revisiting if they haven't been reinstated since and aren't being actively discussed on meta. So, again, I submit that this isn't a particularly compelling problem.

Comment: The "outside the network" [has been broken for some time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345307/73226) - I just got the announcer badge on SO for [a comment left on SO itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947929/how-to-list-all-databases-in-the-mongo-shell?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment64999705_25948070).