# Is this answer a link-only answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, specific-answer

In [Rubocop in html.erb files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025178/rubocop-in-html-erb-files) , [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45031653/38765) has been moderator deleted. I flagged it to try to undelete it, saying

> Deleted by moderator, but seems to be a valid answer. It was possibly mistaken as a "link only answer", but it's not saying that the question can be answered by content within the link, but the answer is that a certain library can solve the problem the OP has.

I got back a reply saying

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

It requires moderator attention, because even someone with 40K rep can't vote to undelete it.

The question it belongs to hasn't been closed as trying to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".

If this answer is genuinely a link-only answer, can someone explain how it's a link only answer? I looked at the tag wiki for [link-only-answer](/questions/tagged/link-only-answer), and couldn't get a good explanation for this particular scenario, nor any of the first page of questions in that tag.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the answer for <10k users?

Comment: @Xufox The answer just says "There is now a Linter based on Rubocop here : [GitHub link]"

Comment: I fail to see how it would *not* be a link-only answer. Care to expand on why you think it isn't?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it's not saying that the question can be answered by content within the link, but the answer is that a certain library can solve the problem the OP has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be one of those questions where the answer, by nature of the subject of the question, *has* to be a link to a tool/add-on/dependency elsewhere *and* little more can be said about it than "download and install this to make it work", regardless of whether or not the question is asking for off-site resources.

The question asks,

> How do I lint .html.erb files with RuboCop?

And one answer — the one in question — happens to be

> There is a linter based on RuboCop which can be found at https://github.com/ericqweinstein/ruumba

(Even your answer, which is accepted, is essentially the same, except it links to a different gem, and contains a "previous version" which according to some ought to be hidden away in the revision history.)

Whether this is a link-only answer depends on whether the viewer considers "There is a linter based on RuboCop called Ruumba" to be an answer in its own right. It answers the question by informing readers that a linter exists, but doesn't give readers anything else to go on other than *that a linter exists*, and its name which can be gleaned from the URL (why [bare URLs are not always a bad thing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315992/is-there-a-preferred-way-to-format-links/315993#315993)). I personally think "not giving readers anything to go on" is a reason to downvote, not delete, but not everyone sees it that way.

[This answer I posted many years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145900/how-link-only-does-a-post-need-to-be-before-its-link-only/145901#145901) alludes to "unsubstantiated content" as a consequence of links breaking in answers. As you might expect, even that term is vague. Again, whether "There is a linter based on RuboCop called Ruumba" is "unsubstantiated" seems open to interpretation.

This answer doesn't give you the closure I was hoping I could, but I'm on the fence on this one and would not have acted on your flag. But if I had to guess, perhaps "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" was chosen to mean "I don't see enough value in this answer to consider it for undeletion — there are bigger fish to fry." That's the reason that would make the most sense to me, not that I thoroughly agree with it.